# Upgraded to Mercurial higher version on Windows: Cannot clone a repo: get abort message because cannot find web.cacerts

Tags: windows, mercurial

This is on Windows 7. I had Mercurial 2.3.2 installed earlier and had some repositories and had pushed them to my Bitbucket account, done some edits and then commits, etc. All that had worked fine.

Recently I uninstalled Mercurial 2.3.2 and installed 2.6.2.

Then I tried to clone one of my Bitbucket repositories to a directory on my machine, to work on it.

The command used was:

hg clone https://bitbucket.org/vasudevram/xtopdf

(I also tried replacing https with http in the above command.)

Both versions of the command did not work. The error message was:

abort: could not find web.cacerts: C:\Program Files\Mercurial-2.3.2\cacert.pem

I had uninstalled Mercurial properly (AFAIK) via the Windows Control Panel uninstall option.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: I saw this page: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/63/cannot-pull-push-to-https-server-with-self and tried the hg clone --insecure option mentioned there, and it seems to have worked. Is there any security issue with this?

Comment: You're no worse off than you were before, but see my answer for what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've found `--insecure` which is what Mercurial was before it started checking certificates, but you're better off following the instructions here to either add a certificate store that Mercurial can find or whitelist the fingerprints of the certs you trust in your hgrc file:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates

Comment: Thanks, will check that option out.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this issue is new with Mercurial 2.6.2? Because I had 2.3.3 earlier and did not have this issue, IIRC. I should ask on the Mercurial mailing list too, and will do that, but checking in case you know. I'm a bit confused because the link you gave says: "The Windows installer for Mercurial 1.7.3 (and corresponding TortoiseHg installers) are now safe by default. They now check the validity of the identity of the server you connect to with the root certificates." That seems to imply that this security issue should not be there from 1.7.3 onwards ...

Comment: Also, for the same project for which I used the --insecure option, interestingly, though clone worked, push did not work. Got the same kind of error as mentioned in the beginning. Checking it out ...

Comment: You're misunderstanding things.  THe "issue" existed _before_ 1.7 and it was that Mercurial **wasn't** checking certificates like anything that wants to correctly implement SSL/TLS does.  So now you need to do one of 3 things: (1) tell Mercurial to be inecure or (2) provide a root CA store or (3) provide the fingerprint of specific certificates you trust.